# How to use Z-index to bring modal login screen to the top layer of page?

Tags: css, z-index

How to use Z-index to bring modal login screen to the top layer of page? try to login from the dropdown menu

how can i make the modal login screen accessed from the top left, be the top layer on the index ?

EDIT:try to login in from the top left menu and you will see, thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG82H.jpg

Comment: z-index? page looks fine, whats the problem? are you just trying to move your login screen to top left?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: try to login in from the top left menu and you will see, thanks

Comment: just tried logging in and it seems to work. what is the problem exactly?

Comment: the login modal is hiding underneath my forums

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in the modals container. If you still have problems, try using bootstraps modal http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp. And FYI I was on top for me, with no problem.

```
z-index: 9999;
```